# Code igniter application error

Tags: php, codeigniter

I got this error while i was installing a Codeigniter application in my Cpanel. The strange thing is it is working very well in my localhost but not in my Cpanel.
And I updated all the required fields with apt credentials..

#### Error

> A Database Error Occurred
> Unable to connect to your database server using the provided settings.
> Filename: core/Loader.php
> Line Number: 346

Comment: I'm not sure this is the right site as it looks more like an administration issue rather than a code one

Comment: im understanding from which side the issue is but plz help me.. its an urgent important thing

Comment: The database credentials are almost certainly different from your localhost one. You need to use the correct credentials (as the error message makes abundantly clear).

Comment: can you change the database configuration page correctly..if you have not problem plz share that file

Comment: all the credentials are correct and exact i checked it for 5times alphabet to alphabet..
This iis the code

Comment: $active_group = 'default';
$active_record = TRUE;
$db['default']['hostname'] = 'localhost';
$db['default']['username'] = 'root';
$db['default']['password'] = '';
$db['default']['database'] = 'school';

$db['default']['dbdriver'] = 'mysql';
$db['default']['dbprefix'] = '';
$db['default']['pconnect'] = TRUE;
$db['default']['db_debug'] = TRUE;
$db['default']['cache_on'] = FALSE;
$db['default']['cachedir'] = '';
$db['default']['char_set'] = 'utf8';
$db['default']['dbcollat'] = 'utf8_general_ci';
$db['default']['swap_pre'] = '';
$db['default']['autoinit'] = TRUE;
$db['default']['stricton'] = FALSE;

Comment: and i edited all the credenials correctly in the above places

Comment: How can password be null on your live server with username root ? These seems credentials for localhost

Also,this error coming up when database credentials are not proper in file

Comment: See im saying that in the above code i updated with right credentials but at this time im unable to keep the credentials there here are example one @tss

Comment: $active_group = 'default';
$active_record = TRUE;
$db['default']['hostname'] = 'domain';
$db['default']['username'] = 'name';
$db['default']['password'] = 'pass';
$db['default']['database'] = 'school';
$db['default']['dbdriver'] = 'mysql';
$db['default']['dbprefix'] = '';
$db['default']['pconnect'] = TRUE;
$db['default']['db_debug'] = TRUE;
$db['default']['cache_on'] = FALSE;
$db['default']['cachedir'] = '';
$db['default']['char_set'] = 'utf8';
$db['default']['dbcollat'] = 'utf8_general_ci';
$db['default']['swap_pre'] = '';
$db['default']['autoinit'] = TRUE;
$db['default']['stricton'] = FALSE;

Comment: on your server you need to create a mysql user and password. without these you wont be able to connect

Comment: @Nikhilkumar You need to follow up with your question and comments provided

Comment: I have done all the steps creating Uname and password n placing them in database.php file and i verified all the steps but its not working in my Hosintg but its working in other hostings.

Comment: $db['default']['hostname'] = 'localhost'; $db['default']['username'] = 'school1'; $db['default']['password'] = 'school@123'; 
$db['default']['database'] = 'domainname-school';